# Error establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: server, firewall, mssql

Welcome, After installing MS SQL Server on Ubuntu and trying to connect it shows the following:

```
~$ sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "SELECT GETDATE();" 
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2AF9.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi WPPlumber The Error message does clearly shoes the you do not get a connection on tcp level.
Best Guess: the hostname `.\SQLEXPRESS` is not a real hostname and the host running the `sqlcmd` cannot resolve the name to an IP Adress.

Try `SQLEXPRESS` or `SQLEXPRESS.<domain>` or only the `IP Adress`.
Maybe you need another option, a working command looks like

```
./sqlcmd -S localhost  -U SA -Q "SELECT GETDATE();"
```

the `localhost` can be replaced with you real `hostname` / `IP`.